# program to emulate web browsing

Tags: web, testing, load-testing

I develop Web cache application for video content. I need to test it with sites like Youtube. Are there any applications which can be used to emulate random browsing of Youtube so I can stress-load my cache proxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at jmeter or some of the performance testing tools that use selenium.

Comment: I tried jmeter but the problem is that since it is not a browser and does not render the content it only downloads static resources while I'm interested in downloading the media files.

Comment: The aforementioned Selenium might work for you, since it does emulate the browser.